# how to add msoeffects to vse objects in microsoft powerpoint?

Tags: vba, effects, powerpoint-2010

I have created a powerpoint with vse textboxes so that they could be used to calculate formulas for me, but now the boss would like them to match all of the other objects that were not added with the developer tab, because those standard run of the mill powerpoint objects can have animations added to them in the animation tab of power point but with the VSE textboxes i cannot add animations this way, and i want to have them simply appear at a certain timed interval.  I have picked apart and rewritten the code many times so it might be alittle choppy, but this is what i have:

```
Public Sub SimpleAnimation()
Dim aSlide As Slide
Dim ashape As Shape
Dim animBehavior As AnimationBehavior
Dim aeffect As Effect


Set aSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
Set ashape = aSlide.Shapes(TextBox2)
Set aeffect = ActivePresentation.Slides(3).TimeLine.MainSequence(3)


aeffect.EffectType = msoAnimEffectAppear





End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're talking about what'd be called ActiveX shapes or developer shapes if you added them within PPT itself.  IOW, the usual controls you'd normally see on a user form.

These can't be animated ... try adding them manually in PPT itself; you'll see that all of the animation options are disabled/grayed out.

You might be able to fake it satisfactorily by creating two slides, duplicates of one another except that the second one has the text controls; then by adding slide transitions, you can have the control seem to appear as though animated.